# Import jars in modularized application

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I develop an Java EE application that is divided in several maven modules. One of module is build as war. I want to import in other module that module. Both modules will be war. How can I proceed to import as dependencies both jars form war module, and also classes that build from sources?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot completely follow your description. I got that you build a multi-module Maven project, which contains one war and several jars. You want to put classes into the war and into the jars as well.

For that, you have the source code of the war in `src/main/java` inside the war module and you reference the jars you need as dependencies in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: I add a proposition which removes ambiguity. So, both modules is war, source module and module in witch is add that dependency.

Comment: Add an additional module of packaging jar. Put all classes that should be used in more than one war into this additional module. Then use this additional module as dependency in both wars. A war is not meant to be a dependency of another war, so you need to put shared classes into a separate module.